# Resource Id #14

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display information from multiple rows. Without changing the majority of my code, how can I echo the multiple rows on my webpage that have `user_id_offerer` = '$offerer'. I did echo the mysql query and I got the result of Resource Id #14 and I understand a while loop is necessary, but it seems like there is a problem with mysql. How do I fix this?

Clarification: When I ran the code with the while loop, I received an infinite loop of the first row. I did not receive each individual row that had `user_id_offerer` = 'offerer'. How do I fix this without having to do a major re-write of the code.

```
function ergo_data ($offerer) {

  $data = array();
  $offerer = (int)$offerer;

  $func_num_args = func_num_args(); 
  $func_get_args = func_get_args();

  if ($func_num_args > 1) {
          unset($func_get_args[0]);
      $fields ='`' .  implode ('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
      $data = mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `ergo` WHERE `user_id_offerer` = '$offerer'"));
      return $data;
  }
}

if (logged_in() === true) { 
  $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $ergo_data = ergo_data($session_user_id, 'primary_key', 'user_id_offerer', 'user_id_seeker', 'ergo', 'ergo_time_submitted');
}

echo $ergo_data['ergo'] . '<br>'; 
echo username_from_user_id($ergo_data['user_id_offerer']) . '<br>'; 
echo username_from_user_id($ergo_data['user_id_seeker']) . '<br>'; 
echo $ergo_data['ergo_time_submitted'];`
```

Comment: Echoing multiple rows simply requires a loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: A while loop is not necessary if you only have one row. Still, it is unclear what you're trying to do or what the error/problem is.

Comment: When I ran the code with the while loop, I received an infinite loop of the first row. I did not receive each individual row that had user_id_offerer = 'offerer'. How do I fix this without having to do a major re-write of the code.

Comment: "*an infinite loop of the first row*"? You're probably using the `implode()` function even with a while loop that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to return the result of mysql_query from your ergo_data() function (instead of the result of mysql_fetch_assoc), then call mysql_fetch_assoc in the loop:

```
// inside ergo_data(), change
// $data = mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_query("SE ...
// to: 
function ergo_data ($offerer) {
  ...
  return mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `ergo`....");
}
...
if (logged_in() === true) { 
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query_result = ergo_data($session_user_id, 'primary_key', 'user_id_offerer', 'user_id_seeker', 'ergo', 'ergo_time_submitted');
    while($ergo_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
        echo $ergo_data['ergo'] . '<br>'; 
        echo username_from_user_id($ergo_data['user_id_offerer']) . '<br>'; 
        echo username_from_user_id($ergo_data['user_id_seeker']) . '<br>'; 
        echo $ergo_data['ergo_time_submitted'];
    }
}
```